# How to filter emails with Imap from a specific sender in C#?

Tags: c#, imap, mimekit

Instead of getting the number 1 - because there is only one sender that has sent a single email to my inbox with the specified email, instead I get the number 19.

```
using(ImapClient client = new ImapClient())
            {
                client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                client.Authenticate("a.t@gmail.com", "pass");
                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                var count = inbox.Search(SearchQuery.CcContains("b.c@gmail.com"));

                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }
```

Comment: `Search` returns a list of matched mail UIDs ... see http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_IMailFolder_Search_2.htm, so you may want to check what type `count` actually is. I am guessing "19" is that mail's UID.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I have been reading the docs for some time but I am not being able to find how to filter by sender email.

Comment: For all I know you do filter. You are just not getting back, what you think you get. Just because that mail is the first and only mail in that inbox, does not mean, it must have a UID of "1".

Comment: @Fildor I simply had to append .Count in the end.... First time working with Imap and I am simply reading the documentation and try to accomplish the task I was given step by step...

Comment: That's the way to go. You'll get used to reading that kind of stuff. Problem was, the `Search` method doesn't return an int count. It returns a list of mail IDs, so you had to get the number of ids in it to get to the count. The Id themselves can be used to fetch a specific mail.

Comment: @Fildor I appreciate it! Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fildor mentioned in a comment Search() returns the list of unique ids. Therefore try

```
var count = inbox.Search(SearchQuery.CcContains("b.c@gmail.com")).Count;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I simply had to append .Count - it meets my requirements. Can you please explain me what is the use of UID while we filter? And thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: As @Fildor mentioned this is what the API of MimeKit specifies (http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_IMailFolder_Search_2.htm). It returns a list of UID's, because thats what the developers of the Mail-Library intended.When you look at the page, you can see that you can use the UID to get the message of the Email and further things